# How to modify pytest arguments?

Tags: python, automated-tests, pytest, xdist

I found out for this purpose I can use PyTest function pytest_load_initial_conftests()

https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#dynamically-adding-command-line-options

But I can't implement this example (see link) correctly.

**pytest_load_initial_conftests()** doesn't even start (looked through debug).
Tests run ordinary without any params (one thread), but I expected "-n" param.

I installed pytest and xdist. 
Only two file in project. There are no pytest.ini.

What am I doing wrong? Please help run it.

**conftest.py**

```
import pytest
import os
import sys


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--some_param', action='store', help='some_param', default='')


def pytest_configure(config):
    some_param = config.getoption('--some_param')


def pytest_load_initial_conftests(args):
    if "xdist" in sys.modules:
        import multiprocessing
        num = max(multiprocessing.cpu_count() / 2, 1)
        args[:] = ["-n", str(num)] + args
```

**test_t1.py**

```
import inspect
from time import sleep
import os
import pytest


class Test_Run:

    def test_1(self):
        body()

    def test_2(self):
        body()

    def test_3(self):
        body()

    def test_4(self):
        body()

    def setup(self):
        pass

    def teardown(self):
        pass


def body():
    sleep(5)
```

Comment: Isn't this what `-n auto` does ?

Comment: Anyway, you may need to `import xdist` before it appears in `sys.modules`. And you can use `try: import xdist except ImportError: pass` so that the import doesn't stop the execution if it is not present.

Answer (score 4):

### Add extra plugin to make pytest arguments dynamic

As per the [API documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_load_initial_conftests), `pytest_load_initial_conftests` hook will not be called in `conftest.py` file and it can be used in plugins only.

Further, [pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/writing_plugins.html#making-your-plugin-installable-by-others) mentions how to write custom plugin for pytest and make it installable.

Following this:

##### create following files in root directory

```
- ./setup.py
- ./plugin.py
- ./tests/conftest.py
- ./pyproject.toml
```

```py
# contents of ./setup.py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='my_project',
    version='0.0.1',
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
        ], # feel free to add if you have any
        "pytest11": ["custom_args = plugin"]
    },
    classifiers=["Framework :: Pytest"],
)
```

notice `python11` here, it is reserved for adding pytest plugins as I have read.

```py
# contents of ./plugin.py

import sys

def pytest_load_initial_conftests(args):
    if "xdist" in sys.modules:
        import multiprocessing
        num = max(multiprocessing.cpu_count() / 2, 1)
        args[:] = ["-n", str(num)] + args
```

```py
# contents of ./tests/conftest.py

pytest_plugins = ["custom_args"] # allows to load plugin while running tests

# ... other fixtures and hooks
```

finally, pyproject.toml file for the project

```ini
# contents of ./pyproject.toml

[tool.setuptools]
py-modules = []

[tool.setuptools]
py-modules = []

[build-system]
requires = [
  "setuptools",
]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "my_package"
description = "My package description"
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.8"
classifiers = [
    "Framework :: Flask",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
]
dynamic = ["version"]
```

This will Dynamically add `-n` argument with value which enables parallel running based on the number of CPUs your system has.

Hope this helps, feel free to comment.

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs on `pytest_load_initial_conftests`:

> Note: This hook will not be called for conftest.py files, only for
> setuptools plugins.

https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_load_initial_conftests

Probably it shouldn't be mentioned on that page that you found.

Edit: update docs url

Comment: So given this, where should the `pytest_load_initial_conftests` function be placed for it to be called?

Comment: @Antidemiurge Checkout my answer below. Took almost whole day to read docs 